# Monitoring API for site (hosted on Linux)

Tags: php, monitoring

I have a php site about to go live (With Flex on the UI side) and was wondering what my options are for monitoring. I'm looking for some form of api which is the equivalent to .NET performance counters/ASP.NET health monitoring.

Ideally, I would like to get stuff like requests queued/responses served in ms, and related stats so I can graph them in Flex. I don't mind if I have to use Python or Ruby.

What are my options? I can't seeem to find anything in PHP which is as substantial in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

For monitoring my site, I use [munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/) which provides some nice graphs.  As well, you can turn on some internal Apache statistics with mod_status and mod_info.

And for the real quick and dirty monitoring, on my home machine I poke my colo site ever 15 minutes with the following cron entry:

```
*/15 * * * * if ! wget --load-cookies $HOME/.mozilla/fake/cookies.txt --save-cookies $HOME/.mozilla/fake/cookies.txt -q --spider http://navaid.com/CoPilot/ ; then echo "CoPilot site is down" ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had quite a few recommendations for using munin. I guess I'll get the source and try it out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested by PHP monitoring extensions like [Pinba](http://pinba.org/) or [APM](http://code.google.com/p/peclapm/).